# How to check if prepared statement already exists in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, prepared-statement, pg

Using the PG Gem for Postgresql in Ruby, how would you check to see if a prepared statement already exists?

Comment: What do you mean as "prepared statements in Ruby" ?

Ruby statements do not need any preparation.

Comment: @SergeyBolgov: *prepared statements* is database terminology: http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#prepare-instance_method and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html

Comment: Correct. "prepared statement" is a database terminology. So the question "check if prepared statement already exists in Ruby" makes no sense. Probably, the OP wanted to ask about "prepared statement in Rails+Postgres". The question needs clarification.

Comment: @SergeyBolgov: They're using accessing PostgreSQL using Ruby's `pg` gem and they want to know how to check if a particular prepared statement already exists. Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967333/prepared-statements-already-exists, or you can use http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/view-pg-prepared-statements.html

Comment: I restated the question for clarification. I'm not able to find the answer for this anywhere. Thank you akonsu, although I didn't ask how to deallocate a prepared statement using the PG Gem in ruby, that was a problem I ran into yesterday. Up vote for helpfulness :)

Comment: Actually here they asked the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967333/prepared-statements-already-exists But only got an answer showing how to deallocate the statement that already exists, not to check if it's already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the pg_prepared_statements view to see if the name is used:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/view-pg-prepared-statements.html

Credit goes to akonsu who answered in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by catching the error that you get when you call describe_prepared

```
statement_exists = true
begin 
  connection.describe_prepared(statement_name)
rescue PG::InvalidSqlStatementName
  statement_exists = false
end
```